# Using Microsoft Graph Client unable to copy/move email from inbox to subfolder on shared account

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have an enterprise application which is registered in Azure. The application move the attachments to a network drive and then attempts to move the mail to a subfolder. The account is shared, however, in Azure AAD there isnt an application permission for Mail.ReadWriteShared as there is for delegate.  Is there a work around for moving mail on a shared account using an enterprise app?

I am trying to copy or move the item to a subfolder on the shared email account however, it doesnt do either. It appears if it is a shared it doesnt complete that. I am not getting an exception so I am not sure how to resolve.

thanks